# Primefaces - add ajax loading dialog while pages are rendering

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Is there any built-in component or hook in Primefaces or JSF to display a `<p:dialog>` loader indicator before every page  is rendered and after it renders to be removed?

For example, I have the following dialog

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="customDialog" id="customDialog"
          modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
    <div class="p-text-center">
        <i class="pi pi-spin pi-spinner loading-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</p:dialog>
```

and I want to `show()` it while my page is rendering, and when page has been loaded, I want the `.hide()` method to be called.

If there is not any out of the box way,what would be the best way to achieve the scenario described above?

Comment: I would ask some questions.  Are you pages loaded that slow you need to show a spinner?  If so have you considered optimizing your performance?   Here is a project where I document a bunch of JSF + PF optimizations you can do to speed up your page loads: https://github.com/melloware/wildfly-faces

Comment: When redirecting a page, you need to use `ajax="false"` as you need to reload the whole component.

Hence this spinner dialog won't work while redirecting to a page.

Comment: Hi @Melloware thanks for your reply, actually my pages load very fast currently, but I would like to take care of any future "heavy tasks" while bean initialization

Comment: @Asgar , what about if I straight access my page and not through any navigation/redirection?

Comment: Either way, your entire tab needs to be reloaded.

Comment: Because JSF is a server side technology you are serving your page so there is nothing for your to show while the server is calculating your page and sending it to the UI.